# Android Studio program seems to be getting stuck at HTTPResponse

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, httpresponse

I'm working on an app in android studio, i'm relatively new to it and i'm trying to pull some information from a website. But I'm running into a problem. My code seems to be sticking at my HttpResponse request. I've stuck a load of debug logs in and the last one to print is "Log.v("ARG", "Trying 2");". I've included the applicable code below, can anyone maybe point out something I'm doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... medURLs) {
        Log.v("ARG", "Executed");
        String medName = "medName";
        for (String medSearchURL : medURLs) {
            HttpClient medClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.v("ARG", medSearchURL);
            try {
                Log.v("ARG", "Trying 1");
                HttpGet medGet = new HttpGet(medSearchURL);
                Log.v("ARG", "Trying 2");
                HttpResponse medResponse = medClient.execute(medGet);
                Log.v("ARG", "Trying 3");
                StatusLine medSearchStatus = medResponse.getStatusLine();
                Log.v("ARG", "before if");
                if (medSearchStatus.getStatusCode()==200) {
                    HttpEntity medEntity = medResponse.getEntity();

                    InputStream medContent = medEntity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader medInput = new InputStreamReader(medContent);
                    BufferedReader medReader = new BufferedReader(medInput);
                    Log.v("ARG", "In if statement");
                    String lineIn;
                    while ((lineIn=medReader.readLine())!=null) {
                        medName +=lineIn;
                        Log.v("ARG", "In while loop");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Log.v("ARG", "failed if statement");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("ARG", "caught");
            }
            Log.v("ARG", "End of big loop");
        }
        Log.v("ARG", "About to return");
        return medName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try httpurlconnection. you can check one of this tutorial..

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html